# cannot specify Target when running FAKE with fsi --exec

Tags: build, f#-fake, fsi

I want to execute FAKE script with fsi --exec because it is so much faster than using FAKE.exe. However, I cannot understand how to specify a target.

This I can do:

```
FAKE.exe build.fsx Clean
```

This I want to do (but doesn't work, it will use the default target):

```
fsi --exec build.fsx Clean
```

Any hints?

Thanks

Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a little extra work,

At the start of your script setup or default a build param and at the end of your script use the default target construct, something like:

```
#I "pathToYourFale\\FAKE\\tools"
#r @"FakeLib.dll"


open Fake
open Fake.EnvironmentHelper

// Process command args as Fake utilities don't work from fsi invoke
for arg in fsi.CommandLineArgs do
     tracefn "arg: %s" arg
     if arg.StartsWith("target=") then target <- arg.Split('=').GetValue(1) :?> string
     else if arg.StartsWith("Target=") then target <- arg.Split('=').GetValue(1) :?> string

...
Your script here
...
...

AdditionalSyntax.RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "target"
```

This should work for both Fake invokes and Fsi invokes e.g.

```
fsi yourScript.fsx target="Yourtarget"
```

The command arg handling is a bit clunky, anybody got a better suggestion on how to process?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks! For all other F# newbies out there I can add that I needed to declare `let mutable target = "myDefaultTarget"`